# Sending emails using sendgrid and Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to follow along with the instructions on how to send up SendGrid to send emails on GoogleCloudPlatform, and I am stuck.  Here are a few things to know up front: 
The directions I am attempting to follow: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid#windows

I have made it down to the section: Understanding the code: importing the dependencies.  Everything up until I think I have understood and completed. 
At this point it lists some NODE.JS  code that has to be implemented.

This is where I am completely lost. I am not sure where to execute this code. Example:

```
const Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer;
const sendgrid = require('sendgrid');
const config = require('./config.json');
const uuid = require('uuid');

// Get a reference to the Cloud Storage component
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
// Get a reference to the BigQuery component
const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')();
```

This is a section of code it says to execute. But where? CMD prompt? a .bat file? somewhere on the google cloud platform? Functions? Storage? BigQuery?

I understand no JavaScript and even less Node.js and I hvae only been working with Google cloud platform for about a week and it is very confusing to me. (I am typically developing in T-SQL so all of this is foreign to me!)

I think I am looking for a very simplistic overview or direction to go in.  I have not found much in the way of online help that I understand.

Bottom line of what I am looking to do is to automate a process that will run every night take some data out of a BigQuery view, insert it into a table, then export the contents of that table into a .csv file on the Google Cloud storage (This is the point I am at currently) From this point I am hoping to make a cloud function that will fire once this file hits the storage bucket and will generate an e-mail and send the .csv file as an attachment to some set recipients.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am close to getting my first project in the google cloud platform completed!

Comment: I believe that all of these node.js pieces of code go into Cloud functions. Now do they go into individual functions or one single function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all just one node JS file. You can see it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/sendgrid/index.js) on Github in its entirety.  Within this file are several functions.  Each one that starts with `exports.` can be deployed as its own Cloud Function.  You use the same file to deploy **several** Cloud Functions.  In the section "*Deploying the functions*", you'll see this happening:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helps, I Am getting an error when I attempt to deploy my Cloud function.  I uploaded the Config.json, index.js, and Package.json files to the cloud storage buckets.  When I go to save/deploy my function I get the following error: 
Deployment failure:
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'safe-buffer'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497

Comment: There is more to the error message but I cannot fit it in the comment section.  I am think I have either uploaded the incorrect files, or I have to do something with them first.

Comment: Please open a new question for this problem and consider marking this one as solved.Thanks.